# Entity Framework doesn't generate all tables from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my diagram in my database:

[image]

but when I use Entity Framework it was like that:

[image]

It hasn't table name `ListSuiteQuestion` but It has 2 new property in class `Question` and `Suite`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irk1m.png)

Comment: That is the way EF handles m:n relationships in a relational database! While the relational database needs a "link" table in between, EF can model two collection properties in both involved entities - `Question` has a collection of `Suite`, and vice-versa. EF will handle the entries into the relational "link" table behind the scenes

Comment: Hi, can you put your code as code instead of an image?

Answer (score 0):

Table `ListSuiteQuestion` is automatically created by sql because in `sql` we don't have something called `many to many relationship (m:n)` and sql creates another table to implement m:n relationship with keys containing the primary key of two relationship tables is also the name of the combination of the names of the two relation tables.
Within your entity framework by accessing each table through another table you have access to that table so there is no need to define it by entity framework. However, if you intend to customize or add a field to a third table you can manually build it into the code and then display it entity framework, though you don't need to.

if you want create it manually in code do like this :

```
 public class Suite
    {
        //another property
        public int IdSuite { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SuitQuestions> Questions { get; set; }
    }
    public class Question
    {
        //another property
        public int IdQuestion { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SuitQuestions> Suites { get; set; }
    }
    public class SuiteQuestions
    {
        public Suite Suite { get; set; }
        public int IdSuite { get; set; }
        public  Question Question { get; set; }
        public int IdQuestion { get; set; }

        //add custome property if you need

    }
```

and config it.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct. A question has a list of suites and a suite has a list of questions. 
If you do:

```
        var suite = context.Suites.Find(5);
        var question = context.Questions.Find(30);
        suite.Questions.Add(question);
        // And update this suite object here;
```

You will see a new record in ListSuiteQuestion Tables with IdSuite = 5 and IdQuestion = 30. The class ListSuiteQuestion doesn't need to be created. 
However, if you really want to create the class you have to add Id to the Table ListSuiteQuestion as primary key.